# Java format milliseconds to uu:mm:ss

Tags: java, time, format

I have the following problem and I couldn't find the best solution for it yet.
Lets say I have an integer with the following value:

`int miliseconds = 65111;`

I want to print it to an stream using the `printf()` function. Is there a way I can do the following:

`printf("Time: %uu:mm:ssT", miliseconds");`

so it will return:

`Time: 00:01:05`

Here I just made up the %uu:mm:ssT part, but is there a way to do this.

Also, do you know a website where I can find all the formatting options, so I can look it up myself next time.

Comment: I would check out the `TimeUnit` api, as shown [here](http://mre-anotherprogrammersblog.blogspot.com/2012/01/java-how-to-format-milliseconds-to.html). Yes...a shameless piece of self-promotion, but it's relevant! And IMHO, a far better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the SimpleDateFormat to format a time from new Date(milliseconds), don't forget that SimpleDateFormat is time zone sensitive. So set it to UTC before using, like this:

```
DateFormat outFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
outFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

Date d = new Date(milliseconds);
String result = outFormat.format(d);
```

(I'm using a similar code in my program for a JSpinner to input a millisecond time value.)

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) feature.

Consider the following sample

```
String inputPattern = .... 
String outputPattern = ....
String ms = ((Integer) milliseconds).toString();
DateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(inputPattern);
DateFormat outFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(outputPattern);

// Parse input
Date date = inFormat.parse(ms);

// Format the output
String output = outFormat.format(date);
```

[Edit] - Updated sample to only use j2se instead of including yodatime.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that one. But is there a way I can do it just like that, with an argument in the printf part?

Comment: There's a way, see my answer. However, it's not as nice as using POSIX strftime.

Comment: Your example is a little verbose. I don't see any need to use SimpleDateFormat to parse in the milliseconds. As long as the milliseconds value stays below the number of millis in a day, 1 hour in 1970 is the same as 1 hour in 2011. Just use *new Date(milliseconds);*

Comment: @JavadocMD Interesting suggestion, which would work well for this special application.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The only thing I get when using new Data(miliseconds) is that It's advanced an hour so 30123 because 01:00:30 instead of 00:00:30 any idea why that is?

Comment: @Timo this is since you are not in UTC time zone. Set the time zone on the DateFormat before using it. (See my answer.)

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
final int miliseconds = 65111;
System.out.printf("%1$TM:%1$TS.%1$TL\n", (long) miliseconds);
```

and see [Format String Syntax](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) for details.

Comment: This answers my question really well. However, is this the way you would do it, or would you do it Johan's way.

Comment: I'd use my solution, but I agree that both are terrible when compared to something like `strftime("%M:%S.%L", miliseconds)`. In Java it could look like `printf("%T(%M:%S.%L)"`.